# Let $(R, m)$ be noetherian local, $\dim(R)=1$. Show $CH^1(R)=\mathbb{Z}/(\gcd([k_i, R/m]))$, where $k_i$ are residue fields of normalization

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra

> Let $R$ be a $1$-dimensional noetherian local domain. Then we have that $CH^1(R)=\mathbb{Z}/(\gcd([k_i, k]))$ where the $k_i$ are residue fields of the normalization and $k$ is the residue field of $R$.

This was noted in a book, but cannot figure out how to prove, or where it comes from. If anyone could give or sketch a proof, I would be much obliged.

Comment: What book?  ${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: This follows more or less from the definitions: Since $R$ is one dimensional and local the group is generated by the class of the unique closed point. The relations are given (as in Fulton's book) using the normalisation which is a PID (since it is one dimensional normal and semi-local, assuming perhaps that the normalisation is finite). The image in $CH^1(R)$ of the class of a closed point in the normalisation is given by $[k_i:k]$ times the generator where $k_i$ is the corresponding reside field.